# How to test event based rule created using DTM?

Tags: adobe-analytics

I have created a event based rule and on submit have given the ID of the submit button. Now my question is how to test event based rule? I test page load rule using **Adobe DTM switch**. But event based rules doesn't show there. Can any one please tell me how to test this?

Comment: I tried 1. localStorage.setItem(‘sdsat_stagingLibrary’,true); 2._satellite.setDebug(true); This gives me undefined error.

Comment: That's gives and undefined error when you run those in the console or just returns undefined? Once you run those, you can refresh the page and see the debug output and the staging library should load.

Comment: Event based rules should definitely show in the debug output. If you are leaving the page, check the console box that says, preserve console output so you can still see the previous page debug messages.

Comment: I get undefined in the console when I type these but I don't see the event based rules are firing. In Omnibug i can see the rules are working but I am not sure what is the best way to test this.

Comment: I was able to fix it. The issue was in my regular expression. Thanks BrettAHale for your time.

Answer (score 0):

## Initialization

They are event based, so they appear after they are initialized, so after submit button click.

## Form behavior

The question is, what happens after you submit button. Redirect? If yes, you have to add some delay before redirect. If not and only AJAX happens, then use DTM SWITCH as usual and you will see it in console. You can either extend console log by `_satellite.notify("My custom event base rule",1);`

Comment: They don't redirect to new page. Thank you message is shown in place of the form. So with _satellite.setDebug(true); I was able to see the rule in the console.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned, the DTM switch is an excellent (free) tool to help with your validation. Using _satellite.notify at the time of the event trigger will allow you to see what's happening in the browser.

I actually use a short-hand global wrapper function that uses _satellite.notify but doesn't require me to write it out each time I want to use it.

You can read about it here:
[Three quick tips for validating your Adobe DTM implementation](http://www.searchdiscovery.com/blog/3-quick-tips-for-validating-your-adobe-dtm-implementation-in-real-time/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you don't have access to DTM Switch, or don't like plugins, Chrome or Firefox, you can call

```
_satellite.setDebug(true);
```

in your browser developer tools console. It accomplishes the same thing as turning the DTM Switch 'Debug' button to 'On'.